# Do not escape new line

Tags: c#, string

How do I not escape a new line \n string in Console.Readline()?

```
string line = "//;\n1;2";
// line == "//;\n1;2"
Console.WriteLine(line);
outputs:
//;
1; 2

line = Console.ReadLine();
// line == "//;\\n1;2"
Console.WriteLine(line);
outputs://;\n1;2
```

I'm trying to get Console readline to not escape the newline and the output should always be on 2 lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To read without new line, you could use:

```
Console.Read();
```

To escape the `\n` char, you could use `\\` to escape the `\` char. There is the [`Environment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.environment?view=netframework-4.7.2) static class that provide some features based on the current environment platform:

```
Console.Write("Your text." + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: thank you. I went with 
            line = line.Replace("\\n", Environment.NewLine);

Comment: Nice, remember to mark it as an anwser to help other users on the future :)